# Laravel 5.4 Three from one relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I could not solve it in Laravel.

I have such a painting making;
Servers (id) <- Products (server_id) <- Sales (product_id)

How can I establish this relationship?

Server #1 -> Sales

Sample Code;

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Server extends Model
{
    public function sales()
    {
        # return $this->hasMany('App\Product'); -> $this->hasMany('App\Sale');
    }
}
```

If you can help, thank you.
Google Translate.

Comment: I solved with hasManyThrough()